# Обособляется ли оборот «как сыч»?

Tags: запятые, фразеология, как, сравнительный-оборот

Почему в обороте "сижу, как сыч" ставится запятая?
Ведь можно сказать "сижу сычом", а по Розенталю в таких случаях она не ставится.
А если перефразировать (например, *я как сыч в четырёх стенах не сижу*), тоже не нужно ставить запятые?

Comment: Только еще в одном месте "хожу" на "сижу" надо поменять. :)

Comment: Александр, можете ещё раз посмотреть на вопрос и ответить? Я кое-что добавила...

Comment: Я сейчас в режиме "забежал, глянул, убежал". Если не будет ответов, то постараюсь потом, не знаю когда.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое )

Comment: Татьяна, так все-таки "**сижу**, как сыч" или "**хожу** сычом"? Определитесь, пожалуйста. А то не понятно, как отвечать. И еще: *Обособляется ли оборот "как сыч"?*

Comment: Мне кажется не нужна запятая, потому что сижу как сыч, это не сижу в позе сыча, а сыч - переносное, в смысле мрачный, угрюмый и тп. То есть не имеется ввиду животное, а имеется ввиду качество сыча. Сижу угрюмый = сижу как сыч.

Comment: Римма, спасибо, заголовок изменила. Возможно, пример из Розенталя не совсем уместен. 
Меня больше всего интересует вопрос, нужны ли запятые в предложении "Я как сыч в четырёх стенах не сижу".

Comment: Буратино, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Я **как сЫч** / в четырёх стенах не сижУ.*

Оборот "как сыч" не обособляется,так как находится в ударной позиции наречия.
Соответственно, здесь значение "сычом".

Автор выбирает нужную  **семантику** (как сыч/сычом), но  он должен выразить это значение, **построив**  предложение соответственно.

Сравнить: *Я в четырёх стенАх, / **как сыч**,  не сижУ.*  Здесь позиция у оборота безударная, поэтому обособляется. Это сравнительный оборот.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что заглянем в словарь:
[сыч](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/147702/%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%87) — ночная или сумеречная птица отряда сов.
◊ Старый сыч. Бранно. О старом человеке. Сычо́м (как сыч) глядеть (смотреть, сидеть). Быть угрюмым, мрачным; иметь угрюмый, мрачный вид. Сычо́м (как сыч) жить. Жить замкнуто, уединённо.

> Вопрос о пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах, в частности при сравнениях идиоматического (фразеологического) характера, не может решаться в отрыве от характера самих оборотов (сравнения общеязыкового типа или художественные сравнения, иногда индивидуально-авторские), состава устойчивых сочетаний, как он представлен в толковых и фразеологических словарях русского языка, и т. д. ([Д. Э Розенталь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=j8i8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=iYY6O2iE3d&sig=ACfU3U25mvGSjscpltt3lch5T-q1bjEi1A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAwvOgqZ-AAxXpExAIHRmfB2kQ6AF6BAgZEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC&f=false))
>
> **Примечание.** Если имеются некоторые отклонения в употреблении устойчивых оборотов (порядок слов, подмена слов в устойчивых словосочетаниях и др.), то выделение возможно: *А на мосту, **как черт, черный** взметнулся плащ* (Цвет.). — ср.: *черный **как черт***; *Нити древесные… Тают, **как дым*** (Н. Матв.). — ср.: *развеялся **как дым***; при уточнении выделение обязательно: *Кто это шагает смело, **как герой**, в предрассветной темени зимнею порой* (Вл. Федоров). — Ср.: *сражался **как герой*** ([Н. С. Валгина](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/#id-6%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-toc), § 90).

Сыч — ночная оседлая птица, охотится, в основном, в одиночку и способна в ожидании добычи неподвижно просидеть на ветке долгое время.

Если речь в предложении идет об угрюмом, мрачном человеке, то, да, запятая не ставится.

Если же поведение человека сравнивается с особенностями поведения птицы, то запятая нужна.

*— Хорошо, Родион... мне поспать немного надо перед ночью, а то **сижу, как сыч,** правда, в темноте ничего не вижу* (П. Л. Проскурин. Судьба. Книга вторая. Не отринь).

*А я себе зарок дал: в чужое общество не ходить; **сижу, как сыч,** один и буду сидеть* (В. Я. Брюсов. Обручение Даши).

[О сычах](https://travelask.ru/articles/sych)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!